# Как использовать обученную нейронную сеть?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Я сделала нейронную сеть с помощью библиотеки keras и обучила на cifar-10.

Теперь, как мне на неё подать одно изображение из папки и получить ответ, а не прогонять сеть по тестовой выборке?

```py
from keras.models import model_from_json

# Загрузить данные об архитектуре сети
json_file = open("neural_test.json", "r")
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()

# Создать модель на основе загруженных данных
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

# Загрузить веса в модель
loaded_model.load_weights("neural_test.h5")

#Загрузить данные
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

#нормализовать данные об интенсивности пикселей картинки
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

#преобразовать метки класса в категории
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

# Компиляция модели
loaded_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="sgd", metrics=["accuracy"])

# Проверка модели на тестовых данных
scores = loaded_model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("Точность сети на тестовых данных: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Сейчас, как видно, сеть может выдать только свою точность

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого нужно подать на вход модели тензор размерности `(N, 32, 32, 3)`, где `N` число картинок, которые вы хотите подать на вход сети для предсказания.

```
Y_predicted = loaded_model.predict(X_tensor)
```

PS даже если вы хотите подать на вход НС единственную картинку, ее надо преобразовать в 4D (четырех-мерный) тензор размерности: `(1, 32, 32, 3)`